# Convert a pattern to a style

Tags: vba, ms-word

This ChatGPT generated code converts text starting with pattern "###" to style "Heading 1".

```vb
Sub TripleHash2H1()
    Dim oRange As Range
    Dim searchText As String

    searchText = "###"

    Set oRange = ActiveDocument.Range

    With oRange.Find
        .Text = searchText
        .Style = "Normal"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Replacement.Style = "Heading 1"
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue
    End With
End Sub
```

This macro works but:

1. It will also convert text following "####" etc. to style **Heading 1**.
   For example it will convert "#### Blah-blah-blah" to "# Blah-blah-blah" in style **Heading 1**.
2. After converting to "Heading 1", it does not delete the "###" pattern from the document.

Answer (score 1):

- `.Replacement.Text = ""` and `.Replacement.Style = ..` only replace formatting. It's same as

[image]

Change:

- Replace formatting first and then replace text

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TripleHash2H1()
    Dim oRange As Range
    Dim searchText As String
    Dim targetStyle As String
    targetStyle = "Heading 1"
    searchText = "###"
    Set oRange = ActiveDocument.Range
    With oRange.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = searchText
        .Style = "Normal"
        .Replacement.Style = targetStyle
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindStop
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Style = targetStyle
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindStop
    End With
End Sub
```

---

*Update:*

```
Option Explicit

Sub TripleHash2H1()
    Dim oRange As Range
    Dim searchText As String
    Dim targetStyle As String
    Dim bMatch As Boolean
    targetStyle = "Heading 1"
    searchText = "###[!#]"
    Set oRange = ActiveDocument.Range
    With oRange.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Text = searchText
        .Style = "Normal"
        Do While .Execute
            ' oRange.Select
            If oRange.Paragraphs(1).Range.Start = oRange.Start Then
                If oRange.Start = 0 Then
                    bMatch = True
                Else
                    bMatch = Not (ThisDocument.Range(oRange.Start - 1, oRange.Start).Text = "#")
                End If
                If bMatch Then
                    oRange.Text = Right(oRange.Text, 1)
                    oRange.Expand unit:=Word.wdParagraph
                    oRange.Style = targetStyle
                End If
            End If
            oRange.Collapse Word.wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This macro works well with respect to the second requirement.  However, it does not work with respect to the first requirement.  
Specifically the pattern `#### This should not change` becomes `# This should not change` in `Heading 1` style.

Comment: Please share a screenshot about before and after change in you post. It's helpful to know what's the expected output.

Comment: @Sandeepyou can't try to use the property [MatchWholeWord](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.find.matchwholeword) in the find object/Method

Comment: @Sandeep `pattern ### to style Heading 1.` is in your first post. But there are four # in your testing doc. You need update `searchText = "###"` to match it.

Comment: @taller I made a mistake previously.  The actual behavior is captured [here](https://imgur.com/KXkzlgK)

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: @taller please check this link for a 
[followup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77582831/macro-to-convert-a-pattern-to-a-style-followup)