# Macro to convert a pattern to a style (Followup)

Tags: vba, ms-word

This post is a follow-up to a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77575197/macro-to-convert-a-pattern-to-a-style) of mine.

Given below is a macro that converts the **exact pattern** `###` to style `Heading 1`.  This was suggested in [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77575240/5651468) to my previous posting.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TripleHash2H1()
    Dim oRange As Range
    Dim searchText As String
    Dim targetStyle As String
    Dim bMatch As Boolean
    targetStyle = "Heading 1"
    searchText = "###[!#]"
    Set oRange = ActiveDocument.Range
    With oRange.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Text = searchText
        .Style = "Normal"
        Do While .Execute
            ' oRange.Select
            If oRange.Paragraphs(1).Range.Start = oRange.Start Then
                If oRange.Start = 0 Then
                    bMatch = True
                Else
                    bMatch = Not (ThisDocument.Range(oRange.Start - 1, oRange.Start).Text = "#")
                End If
                If bMatch Then
                    oRange.Text = Right(oRange.Text, 1)
                    oRange.Expand unit:=Word.wdParagraph
                    oRange.Style = targetStyle
                End If
            End If
            oRange.Collapse Word.wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

This macro works very well but **only if there is no preceding text**.  If there is some preceding text it gives error 4608 at the following line:

```
bMatch = Not (ThisDocument.Range(oRange.Start - 1, oRange.Start).Text = "#")
```

---

Let me explain with an example:

If the Word document contains
[image]

the macro works as expected and the output is:
[image]

However, if the Word document contains
[image]

we get the run-time error at the following line in the script:

```
bMatch = Not (ThisDocument.Range(oRange.Start - 1, oRange.Start).Text = "#")
```

Comment: I have tested the code with exactly same text as yours. It works well. Restart Word application and test the code on a new document. Please add `Debug.Print oRange.Start` to check its value.